# / operator (or some other part of the code) doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple code in javascript that was supposed to validate the length of a phone number inputed in an html form (check if it consists of 10 digits- as it is in my country). 
So here's the function:

```
function check_tel(){
var tel=document.LpData.phone.value;
var i=0;
for(;i<10;i++){
    tel/=10;
    if(tel==0){
        alert("unvaild phone number- too short");
        return false;
    }
}
if(tel>0){
    alert("unvaild phone number- too long");
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

But it always outputs that the number is too long (i>10).
I already checked the value of "tel" variable before it enters the loop and everything is right.
I also tried it with a "while" instead of "for" loop. 
So I concluded it's because of the "/" operator which doesn't work (although I still don't understand how it's possible) or it has something to do with the type of tel...
So what is the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just check number length like: String(number).length?

Comment: Its better practice to use regex

Comment: is value really an integer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every input value is always a string. Using the divide operator on a string is not what you wanted. So you may convert the phonenumber to an int:

```
function check_tel(){
var tel=parseInt(document.LpData.phone.value,10)||0;
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
tel/=10;
if(tel<1){
    alert("unvaild phone number- too short");
    return false;
 }
}
tel/=10;
if(tel>1){
alert("unvaild phone number- too long");
return false;
} 
return true;
}
```

also note that 123456789/10000000 is not 0...

and by the way, it is much easier to simply check for tel.length...

Answer (score 0):

Possible work-around is

```
function check_tel()
{
   var tel=document.LpData.phone.value;
   if(tell.length == 0 || tell.length > 10){
        alert("invalid phone number");
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Edited the code.Return of value is string.thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to do these things is to use a Regular Expression(Regex).
   `/^\d{10}$/` is a JS regex to check if the number is a 10 digit number.

```
function check_tel()
    {
      var tel = document.LpData.phone.value;
      var teleRegex =/^\d{10}$/;
      if(!teleRegex.test(tel)){
        alert("invalid phone number")
      }
      else{
       //do your thing
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's worth also nothing that you can just do `<input type="tel" />` and call it a day. Maybe even `<input type="tel" minlength="10" maxlength="10" />` or `<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" />`... No JavaScript is necessary for this kind of thing.

Comment: minLength and maxLength has not worked for me when i tried with number type input box

Answer (score 0):

Try `var tel = parseInt(document.LpData.phone.value);` instead of `var tel = document.LpData.phone.value;`